# Search array return index in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, syntax

Just pesuocode but this is essentially what I would like to do.

```
Array=("1" "Linux" "Test system"
       "2" "Windows" "Workstation"
       "3" "Windows" "Workstation")


echo "number " ${array[search "$1"]} "is a" ${array[search "$1" +1]} ${array[search "$1" +2])}
```

Is this possible with bash? I could only find info on search and replace. I didn't see anything That would return and index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like that should work:

```
search() {
    local i=1;
    for str in "${array[@]}"; do
        if [ "$str" = "$1" ]; then
            echo $i
            return
        else
            ((i++))
        fi
    done
    echo "-1"
}
```

While looping over the array to find the index is certainly possible, this alternative solution with an associative array is more practical:

```
array=([1,os]="Linux"   [1,type]="Test System"
       [2,os]="Windows" [2,type]="Work Station"
       [3,os]="Windows" [3,type]="Work Station")

echo "number $1 is a ${array[$1,os]} ${array[$1,type]}"
```

Comment: you fail to mention that associative arrays are bash 4  only feature

Answer (score 4):

You could modify this example from [this link](http://fvue.nl/wiki/Bash%3a_Check_if_array_element_exists) to return an index without much trouble:

```
# Check if a value exists in an array
# @param $1 mixed  Needle  
# @param $2 array  Haystack
# @return  Success (0) if value exists, Failure (1) otherwise
# Usage: in_array "$needle" "${haystack[@]}"
# See: http://fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Check_if_array_element_exists
in_array() {
    local hay needle=$1
    shift
    for hay; do
        [[ $hay == $needle ]] && return 0
    done
    return 1
}
```

Comment: -1 for the link returning 403 and the answer being totally "obscure"

Comment: @Sorin I'm not getting a 403 with that link.

Comment: @Dan Fego: I would attach a screenshot if I could. However, the answer is still totally obscure, and lacking even the basic information.

Comment: You're probably right.  But the OP should try something (like a simple internet search) before asking, too.

Comment: @Carl Norum: actually, it took me a while to figure it out. Anyway, removed the down vote, since the now it has a bit more info.